# error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting an interface

Tags: c++, corba

I am compiling quite an old code using MS Studio 8 and getting quite an annoying error:
 error MIDL2025 : syntax error : expecting an interface name or DispatchInterfaceName or CoclassName or ModuleName or LibraryName or a type specification near "exception".

It is an *.idl:

```
#ifndef __UserCORBAException_IDL__
#define __UserCORBAException_IDL__

exception UserCORBAException {
    string xml;
};

#endif//__UserCORBAException_IDL__
```

It compiles using Studio 6.

Comment: "exception" is not a valid *Microsoft* midl.exe keyword.  I seriously doubt it ever was.  Consider the possibility that you ran another IDL compiler back in VS6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are compiling CORBA IDL with the Microsoft IDL compiler. They are separate languages, they just use the same file extension.

I assume you are importing an existing project, and you have accepted the suggested tool to compile the file, however it is the wrong tool.

You need to use the CORBA IDL compiler.

Comment: I am compiling CORBA IDL with omniidl.exe, which generates necessary header and cpp files. This is done prior to the project compilation with MS Studio 8. The *.idl files are excluded from the project, but reside in the project source directory.

Comment: I resolved the issue manually removing the MIDL from the *.proj file.